# Delphi 2007 MDI Form Destroy Sequence Issue

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

I have a weird issue that I can't seem to figure out.  I have an MDI Child form that has a TListView component on it.  In this list view, I add a few list items with data properties pointing to relevant objects.  In the OnFormDestroy event, I do something similar to the following to clean-up these objects:

```
Procedure TMDIChildForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
Begin
  For I := 0 To lvLabour.Items.Count - 1 Do
    TLabourItem(lvLabour.Items[I].Data).Free;
  lvLabour.Items.Clear;
End;
```

Now, this works fine if I close the form itself but leave the application open.  It will go through each item freeing the associated object.  BUT, if I just close the application entirely without first closing the MDI form, when it gets to code above, the items count is 0.  This implies that the items were cleared from the list prior to calling the FormDestroy method.

Because this is happening only when the application is closing anyway, there's no memory leak.  I just have the application set to show memory leaks when debugging and it annoys me when I get the memory leak message and can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the termination process is, for whatever reason, clearing the list view before your code gets to run. But there's a better way to handle this. Well, a few better ways to be honest.

Starting with the closest to where you are, you should use the list view's [`OnDeletion`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.OnDeletion) event to perform item tidy up. This event fires whenever a list item is deleted. Your event handler would have this prototype:

```
procedure ListView1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
```

Inside this event handler, call `Free` on the object held in `Item.Data`. Done this way you are sure that the associated data is destroyed, no matter how the list and its items are destroyed.

The other approach that I would recommend involves more work. Instead of having list items that contain references to the data, use a virtual list view. In this mode of operation, whenever the list view control needs to draw items, or query their properties and state, it calls events of the control to get the information on demand. This avoids you needing to couple the lifetime of your data objects to the lifetime of the GUI that displays it.

Comment: Depending on how the ListView items relate to the data they are referencing, and whether the data is being displayed to the user or just referenced for private use, using the ListView in virtual mode might be overkill in this situation. A smaller change would be to store the actual data items in a separate TList instead, and then continue using the TListItem.Data to reference them for convenience. But when it comes time to free them, loop through the TList instead of the TListView.

Comment: Although I generally agree with the use on `OnDeletion` when data items are stored in the ListView itself, I also advise caution on that, because there have been versions where `OnDeletion` has been broken, either not triggering at all, or triggering at the wrong times or in the wrong order.

Comment: @David: Thanks...  I didn't even realize there was an OnDeletion event for TListViews and I've been working with Delphi for like 15 years now!  I'm actually still curious why the list items are being cleared out when dealing with this specific example, but oh well.

Comment: I'm sure we could work that out, but I couldn't find the motivation to do so!

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I will test the OnDeletion event a bit because it seems the quickest change to make.  While I agree that setting up a separate TList is probably more stable, it's also a lot more work considering that our application does this stuff EVERYWHERE.  But thanks for the tips!

Comment: I understand. Usually it takes something critical to force you to re-architect. For us it was perf with a list view with many items.

Comment: @Caynadian: the items were being cleared because the Form's `HWND`, and thus the ListView's `HWND`, was already destroyed by the time the Form's `OnDestroy` event was triggered. The `TListView.Items.Count` property returns 0 if the ListView does not have an `HWND` assigned. When the ListView;s `HWND` is destroyed, the current item data is cached internally in case a new `HWND` is assigned later.  But since the list items were not available, you could not free your data being referenced by the `TListItem.Data` property, even inside the cache. Thus the memory leak.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks for figuring that out for me!  Satisfies my curiosity.